# iOS Memory Leak after advanceToNextInputMode in Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing Keyboard Extension on iOS 8.3
While developing there is a memory leak somewhere after calling advanceToNextInputMode.

And the Responsible Frame and leaked Object are looks like totally out of my control.

Can anybody meet anything similar problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this *exact* problem. It is Apple's fault. The total amount of memory leaked is pretty tiny though. File a bug report so they'll take it more seriously (I've already filed, but more always help).